# Unable to detect AGP versions for included builds

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oa76F.png)
I am running my react native app on vs code and I encounter this error.
How to resolve it? It was configuring for so long.

ERROR AS FOLLOWS:

> Configure project :app
> Unable to detect AGP versions for included builds. All projects in the build should use the same AGP version. Class name for the included build object: org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuild$IncludedBuildImpl_Decorated.
> <=====--------> 40% CONFIGURING [28s]
> :app

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am unable to post a picture as I am new here.